# Setting up End-User Connection to ODBC Data Source

Tags: sql-server, odbc, microsoft-access, dsn

I need to connect my MS Access (front-end) database to SQL Server 2008 (back-end), using my ODBC connection, for all of my team to view the data in the MS Access reports, forms, etc.  My MS Access front-end database contains linked tables to a specific database in SQL Server, using an ODBC connection (System DSN - SQL Server Native Client 10.0).  Note: My team has read-only access to the database in SQL Server.

The ODBC connection will work on my machine (System DSN, User DSN, and File DSN), but I don’t know what I need to do to configure my teammates' machines so they can connect to my ODBC data source/use my ODBC connection. My teammates do not have Access or SQL Server on their machines; they will be retrieving the Access database through a shared network.

Any help you could provide on how/what I need to do to set up my teammates' machines so they can view the data in the MS Access reports would be greatly appreciated!  Please let me know if I need to provide more information in order to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up as a File DSN, you can then place said file on a network share and your teammates should be able to reference the file to import into Excel or whatever method they want to use to view the data.

Comment: Vigilem, I have the Access database set up so they can only view a form and click buttons to generate reports (and then export reports to a PDF or Excel file).  I don't want my teammates to have to import the data themselves; I want the data from SQL Server already in Access when they run the queries for the reports.  Would that still working using a File DSN?

Comment: Okay, got it. Perhaps I'm missing the point or oversimplifying, but if the data from SQL gets appropriately populated into the Access frontend using the ODBC connection you're using right now, do your teammates need to do anything different than what they're doing? If the data's made it to the DB, it sounds like you're already there if your teammates are allowed to read from the SQL DB.